# Selecting values with a threshold pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to make a list of the columns which for each of those index = [0,43,46] the values are higher than a certain value, for example, 1000.

My data frame looks like this but with more columns.

```
index           asset.assetStateId.10  asset.assetStateId.100  asset.assetStateId.101  \
0.0                  1057.0                     0.0                     0.0   
43.0                  380.0                  1441.0                     0.0   
46.0                    0.0                     0.0                  1441.0
```

So, in the end, I would like to have three lists which the name of the column which the values are higher than 1000 for each row.

Thanks in advance,

I have tried so far this:

```
lista_colunas = list(result_1.columns.values)
lista_assets = []
for asset in lista_colunas:
    if result_1.loc[result_1[asset]>1000]:
        lista_assets += [asset]
```

ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your effort.

Comment: Based on your example you want [0,0,0]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can create `dictionary of list`s:

First select rows by `loc` if necessary, then reshape by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
idx  = [0,43,46] 
df = df.loc[idx].stack().reset_index(name='val')
print (df)    
   Index                 level_1     val
0      0   asset.assetStateId.10  1057.0
1      0  asset.assetStateId.100     0.0
2      0  asset.assetStateId.101     0.0
3     43   asset.assetStateId.10   380.0
4     43  asset.assetStateId.100  1441.0
5     43  asset.assetStateId.101     0.0
6     46   asset.assetStateId.10     0.0
7     46  asset.assetStateId.100     0.0
8     46  asset.assetStateId.101  1441.0
```

Then filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), `groupby` and create `list`s, last convert to `dict`:

```
a = df[df['val'] > 1000].groupby('index')['level_1'].apply(list).to_dict()
```

Another solution is loop by each row and by condition create `list`s:

```
a = df.loc[idx].apply(lambda x: x.index[x > 1000].tolist(), axis=1).to_dict()

print (a)
{0.0: ['asset.assetStateId.10'], 
43.0: ['asset.assetStateId.100'], 
46.0: ['asset.assetStateId.101']}

print (a[0])
['asset.assetStateId.10']

print (a[43])
['asset.assetStateId.100']
```

Comment: There is a lot I need to learn from this answer. thanks a lot! I would end up doing lists and loops until getting there

Answer (score 1):

A pythonic way of filtering a list by the values would be list comprehension

```
[item for item in list if item >1000]
```

will keep only the items bigger than 1000 but won't keep the empty slots between them. Depending on how you want to organize the program you can (creating it from the data frame) do a structure like:

```
for name, values in solution:
    name = [item for item in values if item>1000]
```

This supports also dot lookup so you could do:

```
   [item.value for item in values if item.value>1000]
```

There are many ways to filter